# SocketIO failed to handshake, dont know why

Tags: socket.io, network-programming, cocos2d-x, game-development, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to connect a socket in Cocos2dx with a server in Nodejs but it does not work as expected.
Here is my code:

In HelloWorldScene.h

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer, public SocketIO::SIODelegate
{
public:
...
    // socket.io even\vent listener
    void onReceiveEvent(SIOClient* client, const std::string& data);
    // SIODelegate
    virtual void onConnect(SIOClient* client);
    virtual void onMessage(SIOClient* client, const std::string& data);
    virtual void onClose(SIOClient* client);
    virtual void onError(SIOClient* client, const std::string& data);

    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

protected:
private:
    int index;
    SIOClient* _client;
    TextField* editBox;
};
```

In HelloWordScene.cpp

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    //////////////////////////////
    // 1. super init first
    if (!Layer::init())
    {
        return false;
    }

    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

    // connect to server
    _client = SocketIO::connect("http://192.168.0.105:3010", *this);


    return true;
}

void HelloWorld::onConnect(SIOClient* client) {
    // SocketIO::connect success
}
void HelloWorld::onMessage(SIOClient* client, const std::string& data) {
    // SocketIO::send receive
}
void HelloWorld::onClose(SIOClient* client) {
    // SocketIO::disconnect success
}
void HelloWorld::onError(SIOClient* client, const std::string& data) {
    // SocketIO::failed
}
```

And my server, (which is working well with connect in a browser)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    
        res.sendfile('index.html');
});
var handleClient = function (socket) {

    console.log('connection');

    //testing simple message
  

    socket.on('message', function (msg) {

        console.log('Default namespace received message: ' + msg);
        
        socket.send('echo: ' + msg);

    });
var listen = function() {
    http.listen(3010);
    console.log('listening on *:3010');
}

module.exports.listen = listen;
```

This is the error log:
[Error buffer is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKwva.png)

Is there any solution to this ? I have tried many version of SocketIO but so far nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SocketIO implemented by cocos is incompatible with the version from node. Try allow backward compatible by adding this `var io = require('socket.io')(http, {allowEIO3: true});`